# Buying a new laptop: 32 GB RAM at 2133 MHz or 2400 MHz for $45 more?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am looking into getting a new laptop. I will mostly be using it for internet and Word, but also might be using games/programs such as Star Wars: The Old Republic, Lord of the Rings Online, and Maple. I am also hoping it will last me 5 years.

The laptop currently on the top of my list is currently the **MSI GT62VR DOMINATOR PRO-239**, which has two avalible models, [(1)](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N4MLT6X/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A15EHDQVYNLON8) and [(2)](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B071NVNWM3/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A15EHDQVYNLON8). The only difference appears to be that the first has 32 GB RAM at 2133 MHz while the second has 32 GB RAM at 2400 MHz, but the second one costs about $45 more. Is the model with the faster RAM worth the extra money?

Comment: Rule of thumb: a doubling of RAM speed translates to a 10% increase in overall performance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't see a big difference with +267 MHz, but it wouldn't hurt to splurge the 45 dollars for the 2400 MHz variant. If you choose to overclock your RAM at any point, you'll see a bigger difference.

Unrelated, You might want to consider the [MSI GL62M 7REX-1067](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154623). It is basically the same thing for only $1,100, significantly cheaper than the laptops you linked.

While it only has 16 GB of 2400 MHz RAM, it is already excessive for most gaming or video editing. 32 GB is an amount of RAM you would expect in a server. In addition this variant of the laptop has a 512 GB PCIe SSD instead of a puny 128 GB SSD.

The GPU is weaker than your choices, but not by much. It'll still be [more than powerful](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-1070-vs-GeForce-GTX-1050-Ti) to run VR and the latest games at full frame rate. (The screens aren't even 4k screens)

If you really want 32 GB, you might as well buy this laptop, and then spend 100 or so bucks for more RAM sticks and put them in yourself. (The sales site claims there are empty slots in the laptop for more RAM)

For your use the laptops you linked are way more powerful than you need for what you described your daily use for this laptop will be. So I'd advise avoiding overpaying for something you don't need.